# Google Tag Manager inserting custom HTML outside <html>

Tags: google-tag-manager

We're trying to inject JSON-LD using a custom HTML tag but GTM seems to be adding it outside the html tag.

Is this a config or code issue? And can it be controlled?

All suggestions welcome.

Scott

GTM inserted script Screen Shot.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Please show the relevant code that has been implemented

Comment: <!-- Inserted by https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KMD2S7 -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"MedicalWebPage","name":"Stomach ulcer","description":"Read about stomach and duodenal ulcers, which can cause abdominal pain, heartburn, indigestion or nausea, but usually heal quickly after treatment.","url":"https://www.nhsinform.scot/illnesses-and-conditions/stomach-liver-and-gastrointestinal-tract/stomach-ulcer"}</script>

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't insert JSON schema files like that. Try putting them in the Custom  Javascript instead (in the GTM variables) and making the schema file dynamic.

This old Moz article should help you in doing that:
https://moz.com/blog/using-google-tag-manager-to-dynamically-generate-schema-org-json-ld-tags

Also, be aware of the fact GTM modifies DOM (code on the web pages) after/when it loads, meaning that the schema is appended to the HTML code and not the integral/initial part of it. This is not the recommended way according to Google's search engine bot and some people say it might even be negative for your SEO purposes. Google yourself a bit on this topic and then make a decision.